# Activex control goes to upper left corner when reopen excel sheet

Tags: excel, activexobject

I have a datetime picker control on the excel sheet that keeps on moving to the upper left corner when I reopen the excel sheet. How do I fix it to the cell?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You just need to add the code that "shakes" the control.
At my end these 2 lines of code fixed the problem.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("DTPicker1").IncrementLeft -0.8
ActiveSheet.Shapes("DTPicker1").IncrementTop 0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and noticed that when I scroll down and back up, for some reason it corrects the issue. So I added a macros to scroll down and then back up as a workbook open event. Here's what I added to the "Thisworkbook" object:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveWindow.LargeScroll Down:=1
ActiveWindow.LargeScroll Up:=1
End Sub
```

*Note: Be sure to add to the "Thisworkbook" object (instead of modules or other objects).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the **Developer tab is available**.

**Display the Developer tab**

Click the Microsoft Office Button Office button image , and then click Excel Options.

In the Popular category, under Top options for working with Excel, select the Show Developer tab in the Ribbon check box, and then click OK.

Note: The Ribbon is a component of the Microsoft Office Fluent user interface.

Make sure that you are in design mode. On the Developer tab, in the Controls group, turn on Design Mode  Button image .

**Select the control**.

For more information, see Select or deselect controls on a worksheet.

Right-click the selection, click Format Control, and then click the Properties tab.

Under Object Positioning, do one of the following:

***To make the control stay with a cell when the cell moves (for example, when it is sorted) and to resize the control when the cell height and width changes, select Move and size with cells.***

Note: This option is not available for Form controls.

To make the control stay with a cell when the cell moves (for example, when the range or table that contains the cell is sorted), but keep the control's size independent of the changes to the cell's height and width, select **Move** but don't size with cells.

Comment: Thanks. Done all of these but still it loses its location

Comment: Are you sure its an active x control?  Can we get a copy of the excel document?

Comment: What versions of Excel are you using?